# How select a file from one branch when resolving conflict during git rebase?

Tags: git

Given a git repo with two branches `master` and `feature`. When rebasing the feature branch on top of master using `rebase master` lets say that file `a.txt` contains a conflict that needs to be resolved before the rebase can continue.

I know that I can resolve the conflict in three steps:

1. open `a.txt` in my editor manually resolve the conflict
2. call `git add a.txt` to tell git I have manually resolved the conflict
3. call `git rebase --continue` move the rebase forward

Is there a way to avoid step 1 by telling git that I want the version of the file from the master branch or I want the version of the file from feature branch without having to do steps 1 and 2 above.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes.  In fact, there's more than one way to do it.

The rebase and merge (and cherry-pick, for that matter) commands all take the same `strategy` and `-X` flags to pass to the underlying git merge machinery.  For the `recursive` strategy, `-Xours` and `-Xtheirs` choose one or the other "sides" of files in the case of a file modified in both branches being merged.

Or—this is quite different—in the cases when merge *stops with a conflict*, you can use `git checkout` with the `--ours` or `--theirs` flags, to pick the version from one side or the other.  (You can do this with other commands; here, I'll stick with `--ours` and `--theirs` as these match the arguments to the commands that use the merge machinery.)

This is of course different because you can switch up the choices:

```
$ git checkout main
Switched to branch 'main'
$ git merge branch
... conflicts in files A and B ...
$ git checkout --ours -- A    # takes main:A
$ git checkout --theirs -- B  # takes branch:B
```

Note that this is quite different from the "ours *strategy*" (the above shows the "`recursive` strategy with the `ours` option").  With the "ours *strategy*", something completely different occurs.  Let's start without it, doing the same merge again:

```
$ git checkout main && git merge branch
... conflicts ...
$ git checkout --ours -- A B  # take main:A and main:B
```

Let's say there's a third file, `C`, that git can merge on its own.  When you do the above, git merges `C` and you take `main:A` and `main:B`.  If you were to use `git merge --strategy=ours branch`, though, git would take `main:A`, `main:B`, and `main:C`.  It would discard the `branch:C` changes rather than automatically merging them.

I've used `git merge` above because it makes the "ours" and "theirs" stuff "work right".  I dislike the way git names these, though, because when you're doing a rebase, the ours/theirs version get swapped around, because rebase works by changing to the "other" branch and doing a series of cherry-picks.  That is:

```
$ git checkout mine; git rebase theirs
```

works underneath by doing the (very) rough equivalent of:

```
$ git checkout theirs; git cherry-pick theirs..mine
```

and then afterward, shuffling the branch labels around so that branch `theirs` does not actually move.  (It's not nearly that bad internally :-) but it does manage to make `--ours` mean "theirs" and `--theirs` mean "ours", which is pretty bad *externally*.)

Comment: thank you for explaining why the rebase switches around the ours and theirs labels.

Comment: @torek I always love your answers. Q: Is `git merge --strategy=ours` equal to `git merge --ours --file_with_conflict1 --file_with_conflict2 ... --file_with_conflict_n` where 'file_with_conflict1', ... 'file_with_conflict_n' are all files with merge conflicts?

Comment: @Diana: `git merge` doesn't take `--ours`. Are you thinking of `git merge-file`? (Its usage is different, but it does have `--ours`.)

Comment: @torek whoops! sorry rephrase my question here: 

a. `git merge --strategy=ours`

b. `git merge` then `git checkout --ours --file_with_conflict1 --file_with_conflict2 ... --file_with_conflict_n` where 'file_with_conflict1', ... 'file_with_conflict_n' are all files with merge conflicts?

Are (a) and (b) equivalent?

Comment: @Diana: Ah. No, because `git merge` *without* `-s ours` attempts merges for each file. Some of these will succeed without conflict, thus combining work. Others will get conflicts; the `git checkout --ours` for those files will throw away their work, taking ours only. So we'll get a mélange: some files exclusively from ours (where we changed a file and they didn't, or where there was a conflict), some exclusively from theirs (where they changed a file and we didn't), and some combined (where merge was able to combine work without conflicts). But *with* `-s` ours, Git will *ignore their work*.

Answer (score 9):

You can use:

```
git checkout --ours -- path/to/file
```

Or:

```
git checkout --theirs -- path/to/file
```

...during a merge or rebase to choose a particular version of a conflicting file; because rebasing is [a little strange](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase), `--theirs` in this case would be `feature`'s version, `--ours` would be `master`'s.

Comment: Actually, you *don't* need to `git add`, because checkout writes "through the index", copying the ours-or-theirs version into "slot 0" in the index before writing it to the work-tree.  (Doing `git add` is harmless though.)

Comment: Oh really? I thought I'd had to stage it too, to get it staged as a resolution. I'll update the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that what you are looking for, which will get rid of all three steps, is

`git rebase master -X theirs`

which will automatically resolve conflicts in favour of `feature` (the currently checked out branch), or

`git rebase master -X ours`

The sense of `ours` and `theirs` is counterintuitive as arguments to rebase, as noted in the description of the option at http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase

Comment: If there are two conflicting files a.txt and b.txt I might want to select a.txt from master branch and b.txt I might want to merge manually. Are the commands you suggesting applied to all conflicting files?

Comment: In that case, Ash Wilson's answer is the one to go with :)